# Does zonal statistics do weighted average?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, zonal-statistics

When I compute mean using zonal average in ArcGIS, is it taking into account the 'COUNT' in the value attribute table? e.g. if I have a raster with

```
VALUE     COUNT
1           10
2           20
3           30
```

If I run zonal statistics on above raster, will it ignore the COUNT column? Any references in your answer will be helpful

Comment: I don't know if looks at the count field per se but, use some common scene here. How else would the mean be derived? The cells intersecting a given "zone" are summed and then divided by the number of observations thus, giving the mean. In your example, if the values represented a given zone, the mean would be 2.33. Out of curiosity, how would one "weight" the mean, using count, given that the count is the same as n and therefore is used to derive the mean?

Comment: Do you actually have a count value for each cell that you wan to weight by or is that the count of each value?